# Getting Image from Firebase Storage using Glide

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

I am trying to load an image from Firebase Storage using Glide but I am getting an error .

```
package com.kanishq.wallpaper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.firebase.ui.storage.images.FirebaseImageLoader;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

public class Picture_act extends AppCompatActivity{
ImageView i1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.picture_activity);
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReference();
    i1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_picture);
    Glide.with(this).using(new 
FirebaseImageLoader()).load(storageReference).into(i1);
}
}
```

Gradle File -

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.github.devlight.navigationtabstrip:navigationtabstrip:1.0.4'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I am getting a error:

[image: error]

Comment: You have to create an image loader class

Comment: what is the error ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that with Firebase UI 3.0.0, Firebase has Glide 4.0 support and has changed the way the data is loaded using Glide. According to documentation at Github:

To load an image from a StorageReference, first register in your AppGlideModule:

```
@GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Registry registry) {
        // Register FirebaseImageLoader to handle StorageReference
        registry.append(StorageReference.class, InputStream.class,
                new FirebaseImageLoader.Factory());
    }
}
```

Then you can load a StorageReference into an ImageView:

```
// Reference to an image file in Cloud Storage
StorageReference storageReference = ...;

// ImageView in your Activity
ImageView imageView = ...;

// Download directly from StorageReference using Glide
// (See MyAppGlideModule for Loader registration)
GlideApp.with(this /* context */)
    .load(storageReference)
    .into(imageView);
```

(Source: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/storage)

If you downgrade Firebase UI to 2.4.0, your code should work, however in that case you will most probably receive mixing version errors with support libraries.

Comment: Where should Add this class

Comment: this is the good solution. You must add implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.1.0' and Rebuild project or even restart Android Studio (for GlideApp to be generated)

Comment: Why doesn't the firebase documentation add this?

Answer (score 8):

Try this way:

```
storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        imageURL = uri.toString();
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageURL).into(i1);
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle any errors
                    }
                });
```

So this way, you get a URL to the image in the storage and you load that URL into the glide

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your Ans, but now I am getting this error in logcat _- StorageException has occurred.
                                                                       User does not have permission to access this object.
                                                                        Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403

Comment: Ohh Ok so you have to go to your firebase and change the rules for the storage

Comment: By default, you can access the firebase storage only if you are signed in

Comment: firebase rules :- service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}

Comment: Unfortunately yes :- E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekw: Please sign in before trying to get a token.

Answer (score 0):

( KOTLIN ) It was not mentioned anywhere in the Docs but to have to load images directly from Cloud Storage to your App using Glide you have to include three lines in `app build.gradle` (in addition to other Firebase dependencies):

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.2.0'
```

Though you are adviced to use `kotlin - kapt` instead of `annotationProcessor` for Kotlin.

Then some where in your Project add this class for Firebase Loader. Note that the annotation is very important for the class:

```
package com.your.package.name

import android.content.Context
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.Registry
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
import com.firebase.ui.storage.images.FirebaseImageLoader
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
import java.io.InputStream


@GlideModule
class MyAppGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {
    override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
        registry.append(
            StorageReference::class.java, InputStream::class.java,
            FirebaseImageLoader.Factory()
        )
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
Glide.with(this /* context */)
    .load(storageReference)
    .into(imageView)
```

Any errors? Update the dependencies above also `Invalidate Cache and Restart` your Android Studio.