# java, how to do something until callback

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

here's the interface:

```
public interface BitmapCallBackInterface {
  void onCallBack(Bitmap bitmap);
}
```

and here's the method and calling it:

```
public void downloadImagesFromFireStorage(String imgName, final BitmapCallBackInterface bitmapCallBackInterface) {

  StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
        .getReferenceFromUrl("gs://fake-mc-app.appspot.com").child("imgs").child(imgName + ".png");

  final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

  storageRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
      bitmapCallBackInterface.onCallBack(bitmap);
    }
  });
}
```

### Edit

call it:

```
for (i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++) {
  String couponName = nameList.get(i);
  storageHandler.downloadImagesFromFireStorage(imgName, new BitmapCallBackInterface() {
      @Override
      public void onCallBack(Bitmap bitmap) {
        insertImg(couponName, bitmap); // store image into SQLite
      }
  });
}
getDataFromSQLite();
// and then display Bitmaps to the a list of ImageView
```

### Edit

someone had taught me that the thread will continue after receive callback, so i write a for loop to download all the images from firebase-storage, store them all into SQlite database, then retrieve them out and display to ImageView. But it seems like the thread continues before the image download complete? how can i fix it? Maybe i am misunderstanding what i had learned?

**what i exectly want to do is, download several images, after all downloading complete, refresh the listview**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I hope you are using a CursorAdapter for your listview, and not pulling data from sqlite, to an arraylist, to an ArrayAdapter, etc.

Secondly, you ideally shouldn't be storing listview images as part of the database. You can store firebase links, and then *in the adapter*, you will request the image content (using an image loading library such as Glide, see below)

In any case, what you need to do is  notify the adapter dataSetChanged for *every call to onCallBack, after your image is inserted*, then the list will update *after* the image is in sqlite.

If you want to wait for all images to be inserted before you notify the adapter, you can check  the inserted image position against `nameList.size()`

You might also want to consider just using the `OnSuccessListener<byte[]>` interface for storing bytes into sqlite as a BLOB, not necessarily a Bitmap object. Under that scenario, you don't need that extra interface

However, the encouraged pattern on the Android documentation for image loading in general is to use Glide

[Getting Image from Firebase Storage using Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652380/getting-image-from-firebase-storage-using-glide)

Comment: should i use CursorAdapter under android.widget or android.support.v4.widget?

Comment: Support v4, probably, but as I said at the bottom, just use Glide to handle caching images

Comment: I have read the edited part, i store images in spite is because i don't want to download everytime when app open,  it may use a lot of network traffic(?). If I want to store image in mobile so that the app can be used when no network, which method is better for storing?

Comment: Do you understand what caching means? Have you read the Glide library documentation? https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html#caching-in-glide