# Glide will not show image from FIrebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, android-glide, firebaseui

I'm using Glide 4.6.1 and Firebase 11.8.0 in my android project.
I linked everything with Firebase.

I want to load images from my Firebase Storage using Glide. In the Firebase documentations, they show an example of the following:

```
Glide.with(this /* context */)
        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
        .load(storageReference)
        .into(imageView);
```

But this won't work, since Glide 4.x doesn't support .using() method.

What I'm aiming for is this:

```
StorageReference imageRef = storage.getReference().child("task1.png");

Glide.with(this).load(imageRef).into(ImageView);
```

But the `imageRef` is something like this: `gs://bucket/images/stars.jpg`

Glide can't load from this link. So I tried this:

```
StorageReference imageRef = storage.getReferenceFromURL("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/b/bucket/o/images%20stars.jpg");
```

But Firebase "converts" the http link to gs, which again, won't work.

So I googled the problem, and I found this solution:

```
storageRef.child("task1.png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                String imageRef = uri.ToString();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle any errors
            }
        });

Glide.with(this).load(imageRef).into(ImageView);
```

But the `uri` is not a direct download link to the image.

So the only solution I can think of is using the give http links directly in a string, and using that in Glide's .load() methid, which is not what I'm aiming for. I need to get the direct link from the storage reference to use with Glide.

Comment: It works.  It sounds like you may not have performed all the steps in the documentation for Firebase-UI to set things up.

Comment: Which solution do you mean works?

Comment: Passing a StorageReference to Glide's load() method.

Comment: How should I use FirebaseUI to load the image? How can I use the FirebaseImageLoader() with Glide?

Comment: This thread already has an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48762436/6152620 and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46653041/6152620

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is Working for me :

Add onCompleteListener to your reference

if the task is successful then get the link from task.getResult()

but am not sure if this is the best way, GoodLuck!

```
    storageReference = storage.getReference().child("images/").child(user.getUid());
    storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
          if(task.isSuccessful())
          {
              Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                      .load(task.getResult())
                      .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                      .into(ivProfile);

          }
          else {
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              Log.d("Firebase id",user.getUid());
          }






        }
    });
```